Identify this 00s sitcom about a lawyer
He has his own office, not a firm, where clever, I remember several episodes:

One is about couple that had a prenup when they were young, and now in their 40s the man is suing the woman.
Another one is about a painter. He is a really bad painter but wants to paint so he can leave behind something to humanity from which he will be remembered. At one point he says something like our lives are so short, but Picasso lived a long life because he is remembered.
Another episode is about some schoolboy that is an outsider and a girl that wants to help him in building reputation and self esteem. They both organise a party in some bowling alley by putting cards with telephone numbers in high school lockers. Of course the party is fake and everybody who showed up were turned down, since they were not on the bowling alley's list.
The final episode that I remember is an episode about a fat white rich Buddhist. He had a car accident with a lawyer, and he blackmailed him for money, to settle down.


please try to add some more info, like e.g. the spoken language, the city / country where it played etc.

@FranciscoV. USA

@SSimon: No problem.

This sounds like Ed (2000-2005). While I didn't see all the episodes, it certainly sounds close.
From IMDb Synopsys:

Ed Stevens is a contracts lawyer at a high-profile New York City firm.
  Around the same time he splits with his wife (she slept with a
  mailman), he makes a single error in punctuation when going over a
  contract; and because of the resulting financial loss to the firm,
  he's fired. Despondent, he heads back to his (small) hometown of
  Stuckeyville -- 'Anytown', USA. There he realises he's been missed by
  a lot of friends whom he's missed; and he sees Carol, the girl he'd
  adored in high school. Swept up in roiling emotions, Ed buys the local
  bowling alley on a whim, moves to Stuckeyville, and determines to win
  Carol's heart. His horizons broaden as he settles once more in
  Stuckeyville, and the series itself settles into a charming, funny,
  often serious slice-of-life series focused not solely on Ed but on the
  lovable ensemble cast of people who live and work with him in
  Stuckeyville.


Please add more details why you think this is a good match. We try to discourage one-line answers.

You might want to elaborate in which way this fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.

thank you Kevin, @NapoleonWilson I will try to find episodes and post which one I was remembering
